# During make script, how to manual update make file

Tags: linux, macos, makefile, autoconf, apple-m1

During a make process of compiling software

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/tools/libelf'
(cd /Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/build_dir/host/libelf-0.8.13/; bash ./configure --target=arm-apple-darwin20.4.0 --host=arm-apple-darwin20.4.0 --build=arm-apple-darwin20.4.0 --program-prefix="" --program-suffix="" --prefix=/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/staging_dir/host --exec-prefix=/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/staging_dir/host --sysconfdir=/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/staging_dir/host/etc --localstatedir=/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/staging_dir/host/var --sbindir=/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/staging_dir/host/bin --disable-shared --enable-elf64; )
loading site script /Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/include/site/darwin
loading cache ./config.cache
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD compatible install... /opt/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for elf.h... no
checking for sys/elf.h... no
checking for link.h... no
checking for sys/link.h... no
checking if gcc can compile elf.h... no
checking for ar.h... yes
checking for libelf.h... no
checking for nlist.h... yes
checking for gelf.h... no
checking whether to install <libelf.h>, <nlist.h> and <gelf.h>... yes
checking for working const... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking size of short... 0
checking size of int... 0
checking size of long... 0
checking size of long long... 0
checking size of __int64... 0
checking for 64-bit integer... no
checking for 32-bit integer... no
configure: error: neither int nor long is 32-bit
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/build_dir/host/libelf-0.8.13/.configured] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/tools/libelf'
time: tools/libelf/compile#0.36#0.34#0.95
make[2]: *** [tools/libelf/compile] Error 2
```

The lines above that is outputting all the. `checking...`, which process is doing that?  Is that `autoconf`?

Comment: It is the `configure` script, as you can see make invokes it in the second line above.  That's what's generating that output.